# Best way to display SQL results

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Just looking for a general consensus here. I am displaying results from my database and am filtering and sorting them at the onchange event of a select input with js. This works by adding a new _GET variable to the URL and reloading the page, then using php to select the appropriate results. Would I be better using ajax to do it in realtime? I'm just thinking about what the pro's and con's are of both options...

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would worry about when using AJAX is pagination and page bookmarking, or for people who will forward a page to someone else. You can still change the URL with AJAX, though with some extra work.

Comment: This is true, and to be honest ajax involves more time and (for me) more learning. I think i'm swaying toward leaving it as is

Answer (score 0):

To display the sql results, this will be based on the design/process of your application. There are times that it is best to load the results during page load. And there are times that AJAX is more convenient way.

Here in SO there are already a questions related to yours. I'll just provide a link for you.

- [When NOT to use AJAX in web application development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799912/when-not-to-use-ajax-in-web-application-development)
- [Pros and cons of AJAX-loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582146/pros-and-cons-of-ajax-loaded-content)
- [When is it appropriate to use AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558684/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-ajax)

Now regarding your main questions about displaying the results. As KMC mentioned if you want to bookmark your page and there is a pagination. Reloading the page I guess is much better, if I'm correct SO also use this way.

Now when you should use ajax. If the results is a small or a single data and you dont care about the bookmarks. Also when some part of the page must not be change or you are only updating some part of the pages.

These are only my assumption, please read the link I provided.