# Gmail-like navigation

Tags: php, javascript, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show Ajax requests in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205900/how-to-show-ajax-requests-in-url)

Like in Gmail, using PHP if we need to have similar functionality of navigating to different internal links, how could we do it?

For example, from inbox, a specific email gets opened and when I click back button it takes me back to inbox. The addresses are `https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox` and `#inbox/something` for a specific email.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205900/how-to-show-ajax-requests-in-url/3276206#3276206 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url

Comment: This is in fact a javascript question; you are wanting to use hashes which are client-side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail uses an `IFRAME` to implement history/navigation. When you click some links, it adds a new location by setting dynamically iframe source. Browsers take this as a change in the address, and so add a new history item. You can then use pre/next buttons.

GWT [implements](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=232) similar functionality (on which Gmail is built). Do not implement this yourself, as many Javascript libraries already implement this for you. You can use this  [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/) or this [jQuery](http://www.overset.com/2008/06/18/jquery-history-plugin/) plugins for instance.

There is actually nothing (unless server-side code) to be written in PHP. This kind of history management is totally handled by Javascript and client-side code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response and information.

Answer (score -1):

In case you don't want your app javascript driven and rely on the serverside processing (php) you don't need to worry about the history because every link will actually open a new page which is automatically saved in your history by the browser.

Your links would then look something like:

- mail/inbox
- mail/single/2381
- mail/answer/2312