# Rails response to URL ajax crawling enabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, url-rewriting

The google guide [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/learn-more.html) tells how to format your url with hash an `!` in order to make your site crawlable. A good example for that is the new twitter. If you type the URL:

http://twitter.com/dinizz

You will be redirected to:

http://twitter.com/#!/dinizz

I realized that the redirection is made on the server side, because i have tried to do with javascript and turns to every time that i'd change the url the browser reloads the page,  i am trying to do on the server side with Ruby on Rails without success.

any help?

**UPDATE:** I found another question that address the same problem: [How to show Ajax requests in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205900/how-to-show-ajax-requests-in-url/3276206#3276206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be sensibly done server side.

What should happen is that a client without JS will request the page, and then get data they can use.

If you redirect server side, then they will request the page, get a redirect to the homepage with a fragment identifier, and then get the default content of the homepage.

You have to do the redirect in JS on the client side.

Comment: Hi David, in twitter response header the status Code is 302 Found wich means that the redirect was in the server side.

Comment: It looks like they are doing user-agent sniffing; so when I try it with JS blocked, I get redirected to a blank page. Twitter's approach is stupid and not something you should emulate.

Comment: So are you saying you should first send down a non-JavaScript page with a small JS redirect so if the client does have JS the redirect script will run and redirect to a JS powered version?