# Reloading a page when the url is customised

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

If the current url is `/currentpage.html`

and if I change the url on the browser

```
$('#newurl').click(function(){
     $.ajax({url:"newpage/index.html"});
});
```

How can I get the `/currentpage.html` page to reopen when the browser back button is clicked?

Comment: Did you try to ave it in history?

Comment: @MaxZoom you mean `window.history.go(-1)` ? I do not know how to make the browser back button do this?

Comment: Yes, something like described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: @MaxZoom I've alredy gone through it. But was unable to figure it out. I also read that `replaceState()` was a better option but I couldn't put things together to make the browser back button do it.

Comment: That code doesn't "change the url on the browser" (if that means what I think you mean). You are probably doing something that you aren't showing us.

Comment: Also what do you mean with "url is customized" in the title? That code doesn't do that either.

Answer (score 0):

My take on your question is that you want to save the `AJAX` requests in your `history` as well

There is now the HTML5 History API (pushState, popState) which deprecates the HTML4 hashchange functionality.

**[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)** provides cross-browser compatibility and an optional hashchange fallback for HTML4 browsers.

You might want to checkout this **[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205900/how-to-show-ajax-requests-in-url/3276206#3276206)**